# Is there any alternative ways I can follow without using syntax older than or equal to g++ 4.8.5?

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the the words that are used in a maximum frequency in a text file. The function I wrote works perfectly fine with g++ 6.3.0 however my T.A. insisted that it should work with g++ 4.8.5.

I have been working on this problem for two days now, I searched online but couldn't find anything that would help me. Anyone has any ideas? Here is the function I used:

```
void FileOperations::printMostFrequent(string fileName, ofstream& out) {
     fstream data;
     data.open(fileName.c_str());
     map <string, int> count;
     string word;
     decltype(count)::const_iterator most_occurring;

     while (data >> word) {
            auto itr = count.emplace(word, 0).first;
            ++itr->second;
            if (count.size() == 1 || itr->second > most_occurring->second)
                most_occurring = itr;
     }

     out <<"Most Frequent: ";
     out << most_occurring->first << " ";
     out << most_occurring->second << "\n";
}
```

And the error message my TA sent me is

```
FileOperations.cpp:57:19: error: ‘decltype’ was not declared in this scope
     decltype(count)::const_iterator most_occurring;
                   ^
FileOperations.cpp:57:20: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘::’ token
     decltype(count)::const_iterator most_occurring;
                    ^
FileOperations.cpp:60:14: error: ‘itr’ does not name a type
         auto itr = count.emplace(word, 0).first;
              ^
FileOperations.cpp:61:11: error: ‘itr’ was not declared in this scope
         ++itr->second;
           ^
FileOperations.cpp:62:48: error: ‘most_occurring’ was not declared in this scope
         if (count.size() == 1 || itr->second > most_occurring->second)
                                                ^
FileOperations.cpp:66:12: error: ‘most_occurring’ was not declared in this scope
     out << most_occurring->first << " ";
            ^
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who has taken the time to read my post.

Edit-(By the way I am just looking for ideas and ultimately learn from them, not trying to copy paste an answer.)

**For anyone viewing this question and having the same problems, I am posting the fix here:

```
    void FileOperations::printMostFrequent(string fileName, ofstream& out) {
         fstream data;
         data.open(fileName.c_str());
         map <string, int> count;
         string word;
         map<string, int>::const_iterator most_occurring;

         while (data >> word) {
                _Rb_tree_iterator<pair<const basic_string<char>, int> > itr = count.insert(make_pair(word,0)).first;
                ++itr->second;
                if (count.size() == 1 || itr->second > most_occurring->second)
                    most_occurring = itr;
        }

        out <<"Most Frequent: ";
        out << most_occurring->first << " ";
        out << most_occurring->second << "\n";
    }
```

Thanks to everyone who took the time to answer my questions I learned so much :)

If you are having the same issues make sure to look at the other answers and up vote them too they carry valuable information.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you should post an answer.

Comment: Nonono ... using `_Rb_tree_iterator` will not get your assignment approved.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Why not? It compiles and runs, is it a non approved usage?

Comment: @CanKırşallıoba No it's not. It's an implementation detail that isn't portable. I'll add some info to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*4.8.5 supports c++11, so compile with `-std=c++11` and you're fine.*" would be *my* first sentence when handing in the assignment.

You could follow up by converting the code to C++98.

Since `decltype` doesn't exist and `auto` doesn't mean the same thing in C++98 (it exists but for a different purpose) you need to type the long, complicated types. I suggest making some aliases to some of the map's [member_types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to make it simpler:

```
void printMostFrequent(string fileName, ofstream& out) {
  // helper aliases
  typedef map <string, int>::const_iterator map_const_iterator;
  typedef map <string, int>::iterator       map_iterator;
  typedef map <string, int>::value_type     map_value_type;   // std::pair<const Key, T>

  // ...
```

Now replacement should be fairly straight forward.

```
decltype(count)::const_iterator most_occurring; // easy

auto itr = count.emplace(word, 0).first;        // harder
```

`map::emplace` doesn't exist in C++98 so the next best thing is [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert), but you can't do `insert(word, 0)`. You need to insert an element of the map's `value_type` that we made an alias for above to make it easier.

You must be able to change the value of the mapped type (the `int`) in the map through the *iterator* you get back from `insert`, so it can't be a *const_iterator* - and we happened to make an alias for that type of *iterator* as well.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I did not know such tools existed (the demo link). I will use it in the future :) .

Comment: If I know TAs well, the TA will say, "it must compile with c++98". It's worth a shot, I guess

Comment: @CanKırşallıoba You are welcome. I suggest that you keep the code as-is and go for the newer c++ version. C++11 has a lot of improvements over C++98 and `decltype` is just one of them. Edit: Then, TA failed to make the problem description clear. The code _does_ compile with g++ 4.8.5 just fine :)

Comment: Yeah as Humphrey said, our TA is kind of stiff when it comes to rules, so it must compile in his machine or we get a huge deduction of points (even though everything works fine) :(

Comment: @CanKırşallıoba but what is the rule? If it is that it should work with gcc 4.8.5 then this is fine. If not, then they should formulate the requirement clearly.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well they give us the code they use to compile the program: "g++ *.cpp -o myexe "  this is the one that my TA used for example. So changing it is kinda out of the question. But nevertheless I learned a new thing and that is worth more than grades :))

Comment: @CanKırşallıoba Again, ask the TA to clarify the requirements. I think it is their job to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`decltype` and `auto` are C++11 features. Replace `decltype` with the desired class and replace `auto` with the desired type.

In order to catch the C++11 features yourself, compile with the option `-std=c++98`...or install the 4.8.5 version of GCC...

Here's some more info about why this is. In 4.8.5, the default version is c++98, although you can use C++11 by giving the `-std=c++11` flag. In GCC 6.3.0, the default is C++14. Since the TA is using 4.8.5, they are using C++98 by default. In order to match this, you should set your standard to `-std=c++98`. This is not the only difference between the two versions of GCC, but will hopefully be enough to ensure that your TA can run it.

Comment: Thank you, I have clarified (hopefully) that since the OP is using version 6.3.0, IF they use the specified version 4.8.5, they will be able to catch errors on their own instead of having to iterate with the TA or ask on the internet.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the input I did not know the option to compile with the specified cpp version, for installing gcc 4.8.5 I really don't want to mess up my current cpp setup because I have a final in 5 days so if it breaks I would panic :). I would upvote your answer but I cannot due to low reputation, but you have my gratitude.

Comment: I definitely understand not wanting to mess up your setup! If you continue to have trouble even after adjusting your version, I believe it is possible to have a side-by-side installation of a different version. You might also try testing it on the school computers if that's an option.

Comment: Due to the pandemic we are all at home unfortunately :(

Comment: My school has a linux lab. I can remote into the computers with ssh. I would be a little surprised if you didn't have even 1 server.